# Python two tables merge returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inner-join, merging-data

I am fairly new to both Python and Stackoverflow, so please accept my apologies if I've overlooked anything.

I am simply trying to merge two tables.

Table1: incomeStates

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 48 entries, 0 to 47
Data columns (total 2 columns):
State    48 non-null object
Mean     48 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.1+ KB

    State       Mean
0   Alabama     51912.500000
1   Arizona     56918.401961
2   Arkansas    56431.216216
3   California  73346.414226
4   Colorado    70932.230769
```

Table2: costOfLiving

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 50 entries, 0 to 49
Data columns (total 2 columns):
State             50 non-null object
Cost of living    50 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 880.0+ bytes

    State       Cost of living
0   Alabama     46,055
1   Alaska      53,070
2   Arizona     43,278
3   Arkansas    46,672
4   California  51,386
```

With the following code:

```
netIncome = costOfLiving.merge(right=incomeStates, on="State", validate="1:m")
```

However, I am getting quite a disappointing result where the merged table returns empty values, only the header.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 3 columns):
State             0 non-null object
Cost of living    0 non-null object
Mean              0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes

State   Cost of living  Mean
```

The desired outcome is a dataframe of the respective values for the means and cost of living for all the states. Something similar to this:

```
    State       Mean       Cost of living
0   Alabama     51912.500000   46,055
1   Alaska      NaN            53,070
2   Arizona     56918.401961   43,278
3   Arkansas    56431.216216   46,672
4   California  73346.414226   51,386
5   Colorado    70932.230769
```

Do you have a suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Thank you tons.

Comment: Btw, what's desired output?

Comment: Desired output is a dataframe with respective values of the mean income and cost of living for all the states.

Comment: Then can you please edit the question and show it

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')`

Comment: @user3483203, I have tried that but this addition basically merges the tables one after another. Meaning that the new table has 98 rows where the first 48 rows include the income mean values with empty cost-of-living values, followed by 50 rows with empty income mean values and respective cost-of-living values.

Comment: Then the data you've provided doesn't represent the problem you're having.  Verify that you don't have whitespace etc in one of your `State` columns

Comment: Why 1:m rather than 1:1 ? This could also be from case differences or typos or something. You should verify `set(df1.State) | set(df2.State)`

Comment: Thank you guys so much! It was indeed a matter of a blank space. "Alabama" in one table did not match " Alabama" in the other one. Cheers.